# check for css background color in any child in `<tr>`?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I check for if any child of a `<tr>` contains a `background:blue;` then do something?

```
$('table tr').each(function(index,value){
    if (value.has('background:blue')){
        alert (index); //do something to this row
    }
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>dfgdfgdfgdf</td>
        <td><input style="background:blue; value="test" /></td>
        <td>gdfg</td>
        <td><p style="background:blue;>cvcxvcxvx</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>gfdgdfg</td>
        <td>gdfgfd</td>
        <td style="background:blue;>dfgdf</td>
        <td><div><div><button style="background:blue; type="submit"/></div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>gfdgdfg</td>
        <td>gdfgfd</td>
        <td>dfgdf</td>
        <td>dfgdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>gfdgdfg</td>
        <td>gdfgfd</td>
        <td>dfgdf</td>
        <td><div><div><button style="background:blue; type="submit"/></div></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that ?

```
$(function() {
    $('tr').find('*').each(function(i) {
         if ( $(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(0, 0, 255)' )
            alert($(this).text());
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xHgVf/3/

Answer (score 2):

This won't be quick, but it will work:

```
var $blueElements = $("tr *").filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("background-color") == "blue";
});
```

Is there a reason you cannot use a CSS class to put the blue background on each element? Then you could just use that class to select them: `$(".blue-element")`

Comment: thanks -- but i guess if there are not to many elements then it should be fine -- right?  but adding a css class is a good idea. thanks I will try it

Comment: does this returns anything for you, it is empty for me, `$blueElements.Length` is `0`

Comment: in the end I went with $('tr').find('.blue-element')